# Unsuccessful Publishing/Subscribing of Record with _id parameter

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe

I'm using Meteor 0.6.5 and I'm trying to publish/subscribe to data that has a specific _id, but it doesn't seem to be successful. The autopublish package has been removed. Below is my code:

```
Meteor.publish("currentBook", function(bookId){
    return Books.find({_id: bookId});
});

Meteor.subscribe("pages", {_id: Session.get("currentBook").id});
```

Here is the log output from the Chrome console and it does not contain the object I'm looking for:

```
LocalCollection.Cursor
_transform: null
collection: LocalCollection
cursor_pos: 0
db_objects: null
limit: undefined
reactive: true
selector_f: function (doc) { // 562
selector_id: undefined
skip: undefined
sort_f: null
__proto__: Object
```

Please let me know how I could resolve this. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Code:

```
Meteor.publish("currentBook", function(bookId){
    return Books.find(bookId);
});

Deps.autorun(function(){
    Meteor.subscribe("currentBook", Session.get("currentBook").id);
});
```

- Publish and subscribe channels must have the same name.
- You've wrapped `_id` in an object in the subscribe channel, but didn't extract it in publish. This wrapping is not necessary.
- You should wrap `subscribe` call in `Deps.autorun` if you use parameters that can change, like a session variable.

Answer (score 0):

The other thing in addition to Hubert's answer is that using `.find()` doesn't return the object straight, it returns a lazy cursor which is what you're seeing.

To get the data boxed up into arrays use `.find().fetch()` when peering in with the console.